# Have there been further developments on this scheme for polytope approximations to the unit ball of $\ell_p^n$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, banach-spaces, convex-polytopes

A long time ago I happened to look at, and save (on a floppy disk!) for future reading, a copy of the following article:

W. T. Gowers, *Polytope approximations of the unit ball of $l^n_p$.*
In *Convex geometric analysis (Berkeley, CA, 1996)*, Math. Sci. Res. Inst. Publ., 34, CUP (1999), pp. 89–109.

The volume appears to be [freely available here](http://library.msri.org/books/Book34/contents.html)

According to MathSciNet the article has never been cited, but it raises some questions at the end in Section 7, and I wondered if these had been solved since then. In particular, are the "ST-spaces" that the author defines in this article small-constant renormings of Orlicz spaces?

More generally: are Banach space specialists aware of any interesting developments extending or using the constructions in this paper?